# Creating a Print Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a Print Button that will print a printer friendly version of the currently viewed webpage when selected. How should I go about this? I would like to show a print preview of the document in an ajax / jQuery popup window as well. Users can zoom in, zoom out, rotate the content as well.

Comment: Zoom in, zoom out, rotate? You mean, what they see is what they'll print?

Comment: Correct. It will be a print preview version of the currently viewed page.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I use a CSS stylesheet for print media, and to provide a printer friendly view of the page, I call the page and add the appropriate CSS file on the page. say I have a main.css file to style my page, and a print.css for print media. On the print preview view, I link the print.css file after the main.css file so page view could be re-modified to be more printer friendly. You could have this in your URLs like: **http://....?p1=v1&...&view=print**

so the server side code would attach the printer CSS file. If this is your solution, then you could call the same page URL by adding the extra **view=print** parameter via JavaScript. so the onclick action of your **print preview** button could be:

```
$('#printPrevButton').click(function() {window.open(window.location + '&view=print')});
```

note that above code is a sample mock up and needs more work (like checking for existence of the query string starting ? character, etc).

Comment: If you set the stylesheet's media type to print, won't browsers use it for printing? This would eliminate the need for the view=print and the server adding the special stylesheet.  http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html

Comment: How about adding functions where users can zoom in, zoom out, rotate on the webpage? How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: @PhpMyCode: yes the media=print attribute of the link tag causes the browser to load the CSS for print media, but not for print preview. the print preview is on the same media of the web page, but need to simulate the print media. by using the URL parameters and writing the write code in your server side application, you force the print CSS file, to current media (monitor).

Comment: @farzad Good to know. Is this expected behavior across all compliant browsers? This seems like a very IE (read: illogical) thing to do.